# Getting the uncompressed size of a ZIP file in Node

Tags: node.js, zip, unzip

I've got a zip file on disk and I'd like to be able to know how to get the size of it uncompressed without having to unzip it to disk. I know about `unzip -Zt zipname`, but my code will be deployed to Windows servers, and installing `zip` on them isn't an option. I'm looking for a library or something for Node.js that can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Ship a zip/unzip executable within your application. No installation required.